# Docker Destop is not installing in ubuntu

Tags: apt, server, permissions, docker

I tried to install docker desktop by `sudo apt install` and `sudo apt-get install` but it gives the error as :

```
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/linux/Downloads/docker-desktop-4.12.0-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

[image: picture of the error]

I tried commands like:

```
sudo chown -Rv _apt:root /home/linux/Downloads/
 sudo chmod -Rv 700 /home/linux/Downloads/
```

but still it doesn't work

Can someone please help me with that??

And also after using `sudo chown -Rv _apt:root /home/linux/Downloads/` and `sudo chmod -Rv 700 /home/linux/Downloads/`

[image: I cannot access the Download folder]

Comment: Did you try following the official instructions from Docker? They have repository and package installation instructions. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ the package syntax they give is: sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb

Comment: @captainR0bbo I've followed instruction of installing docker engine from the repository

Comment: Can you show the output of these commands in your post please: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` and `sudo apt update`. Thanks.